# Python - List out of range error in web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have been running this python code and it gives me an error saying

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-6ff1d459c8bd> in <module>
      6 soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html5lib')
      7 df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Name", "Sector", "Price", "Price/Earnings", "Dividend_Yield", "Earnings/Share", "52_Week_Low", "52_Week_High", "Market_Cap", "EBITDA"])
----> 8 for row in soup.find_all('tbody')[1].find_all('tr'):
      9     col = row.find_all("td")
     10     Name = col[0].text

IndexError: list index out of range
```

The code i have user do do the python web scraping is,

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.kaggle.com/priteshraj10/sp-500-companies"
data  = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html5lib')
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Name", "Sector", "Price", "Price/Earnings", "Dividend_Yield", "Earnings/Share", "52_Week_Low", "52_Week_High", "Market_Cap", "EBITDA"])
for row in soup.find_all('tbody')[1].find_all('tr'):
    col = row.find_all("td")
    Name = col[0].text
    Sector = col[1].text
    Price = col[2].text
    Price_Earnings = col[3].text
    Dividend_Yield = col[4].text
    Earnings_Share = col[5].text
    Week_Low = col[6].text
    Week_High = col[7].text
    Market_Cap = col[8].text
    EBITDA = col[9].text
    df = df.append({"Name":Name,"Sector":Sector,"Price":Price,"Price_Earnings":Price_Earnings,"Dividend_Yield":Dividend_Yield,"Earnings_Share":Earnings_Share,"Week_Low":Week_Low,"Week_High":Week_High,"Market_Cap":Market_Cap,"EBITDA":EBITDA}, ignore_index=True)
```

Can you help me on this?

Comment: `tbody` dosent exist, do you mean body?, what do you whant to find exacly? when you use `.find_all('tbody')` you get an empty list back.

Comment: The page is dynamic/rendered after the requests. Secondly, there's a download button, you don't need to scrape the tables, just download it.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to print the variable `soup` you will see that the HTML returned does not contain the information you want probably because the site has a block to avoid web-scraping

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this line of code is returning you a list

```
for row in soup.find_all('tbody')[1]
```

And it expects at least to have two items (python list indexing starts from 0), and it's not.

What you could do is print this item:

```
print(soup.find_all('tbody'))
```

To see what are you trying to access the position index 1, and why is not there.

Additionally if you want to check the length:

```
print(len(soup.find_all('tbody')))
```

It should be smaller than 1, hence the error.

I'd recommend you, instead of printing using a debugger to find out what's up with your code.

The issue seems to be that the website you are trying to **scrape** , probably changed their HTML code somehow.